# Redirection to another controller in Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: spring-portlet-mvc

I have a Spring 3.0 Portlet with two controllers. Controller-1 has the default @RenderMapping annotated method where I run some logic to decide the view to render, say view-1 and view-2.

The Model attributes for view-1 are populated in Controller-1 and for view-2 in Controller-2.

How can I redirect to Controller-2 when my logic needs to return view-2 so that I can populate the Model attributes corresponding to view-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the method in controller-2 from controller-1.

Pseudocode for controller-1's render method

```
if(yourCondition){
    return controller-2.renderMethod();
}
populateYourModel
return view;
```

Although you probably want to rethink this piece of logic. It sounds like the requests are different in some way so ideally you would send them directly to the correct controller.

Comment: Thanks for your input,but what Im currently doing is, calling the `populateModel` in controller-2 explictly which is annotated with `@ModelAttribute` when my condition is met passing the `Model` attribute and then returning the corresponding view. Im quite skeptic whether `@ModelAttribute` annotated methods will execute just by doing a simple call to `renderMethod()` in `controller-2`. Im looking for something in Spring which forwards request to other controller, then execute the `@ModelAttribute` annotated methods and process the default `@RenderMappong` method of that Controller.